# Comma splice in pending edit mouseover notification

Tags: bug, status-declined, suggested-edits, tooltips, grammar

When a 3k-rep user browses to a post that has a pending suggested edit, the <kbd>edit</kbd> link changes to <kbd>edit (1)</kbd>. When you mouse over it, the title text displayed is:

> 1 edit to this post is pending, please review it

The comma should be a semicolon.

Alternatively it could be rephrased to something like "Please review 1 pending edit to this post".

Comment: Someone's been hanging out on [english.se].

Comment: Comma splices are not always errors in English, and the example you quoted is a perfect example of a case where a comma splice is acceptable, even preferable.